# Javascript DataTables columnDefs visible targets from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datatables

I have a datatable for which the columns that should be invisible are from an array `invisibleItems`

```
 "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": invisibleItems }
```

but the thing is that all my columns are visible when I'm opening the page. The `invisibleItems` array comes from a cookie so every time I'm opening the page it should "remember" the invisible columns. It is possible to add the invisible columns from an array?
I've also tried `invisibleItems.join()` to make the array as a string but same thing.

Comment: As I said on the forum, it would be worth displaying `invisibleItems` here so we can see its format. It should be an integer array, like [1,2] - see example here: http://live.datatables.net/vunecumo/1/edit

Comment: @colin0117 the array is integer, that's my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work ;)

```
var invisibleItems = [1,2];
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs: [{
    visible: false, targets: invisibleItems
  }]
});
```